# how to sort a list in Vala using custom Comparator

Tags: sorting, vala

I'm trying to get a directory listing and sort it into last modified time order using Vala.

I've got the directory listing part into a List < FileInfo >.
But I cannot figure out how to sort the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done via the the `sort(CompareFunc<G> compare_func)` method in the `List` class. You can read more about it [here](http://www.valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.List.sort).

A basic example for strings would be:

```
list.sort((a,b) => {
    return a.ascii_casecmp(b);
});
```

The return value of the function passed to `sort()` is the same as the ISO C90 `qsort(3)` function:

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

As you're interested in modify time, the `FileAttribute` you're looking for is [TIME_MODIFIED](http://www.valadoc.org/#!api=gio-2.0/GLib.FileAttribute.TIME_MODIFIED) which you would get by calling the appropriate `get_attribute_*` method of `FileInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int main (string[] args) {
var directory = File.new_for_path ("/var/db/pkg");
var glib_list = new GLib.List<FileInfo> ();
try {
    var enumerator = directory.enumerate_children (FileAttribute.TIME_MODIFIED, FileQueryInfoFlags.NOFOLLOW_SYMLINKS);
    FileInfo file_info;
    while ((file_info = enumerator.next_file()) != null) {
        glib_list.append(file_info);
    }
} catch(Error e) {
    stderr.printf ("Error: %s\n", e.message);
}
// Lets sort it.
CompareFunc<FileInfo> my_compare_func = (a, b) => {
    long c = a.get_modification_time().tv_sec;
    long d = b.get_modification_time().tv_sec;
    return (int) (c > d) - (int) (c < d);
};
glib_list.sort(my_compare_func);
foreach (FileInfo file_info in glib_list) {
    stdout.printf ("%s\n", file_info.get_name());
}
return 0;
```

}